# Отделить данные DataGrid пустой строкой при заполнении C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

подскажите пожалуйста можно-ли при заполнении DataGrid WinForm отделять данные пустой строкой, например: производим выгрузку из БД в список List сотрудников предприятия работающих в выбранные день:

```
Вася - инженер
Вася - электрик
Петя 2 - инженер
Алиса - бухгалтер
Петя - инженер 
Наташа - кладовщик
Саша - электрик
```

Нужно по должности сотрудника произвести сортировку и поместить всех инженеров друг за другом сделать отступ строки, тоесть отделить сотрудников, затем идут все электрики и т.д.
Заполняется таблица с помощь цикла foreach.

```
foreach(var u in user)
{
  dataGrid.Rows.Add(u.Name, u.Position);
}
```

Comment: Из какой графической библиотеки этот datagridview? WinForms, WPF, что-то другое?

Comment: Может, лучше динамически создавать датагриды (или листбоксы) для каждой профессии?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Добрый день, обновил данные, UI библиотека WinForm. По поводу динамики не совсем пока понимаю как это реализовать, возможно это будет даже правильнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дано:
Класс User:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

Грид с двойной буферизацией (чтобы не мерцал при отрисовке):

```
public class DoubleBufferedDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool DoubleBuffered => true;
}
```

Делаем в DataGridView две колонки:

```
dataGridView.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");
dataGridView.Columns.Add("Position", "Position");
```

Имеется список с данными:

```
var list = new List<User>
{
    new User{ Name="Вася",  Position="инженер" },
    new User{ Name="Вася",  Position="электрик" },
    new User{ Name="Петя 2",Position="инженер" },
    new User{ Name="Алиса", Position="бухгалтер" },
    new User{ Name="Петя",  Position="инженер" },
    new User{ Name="Наташа",Position="кладовщик" },
    new User{ Name="Саша",  Position="электрик" }
};
```

Группируем данные по профессии и помещаем в грид, добавляя пустые строки:

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(user => user.Position);

foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    foreach (var user in group)
    {
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(user.Name, user.Position);
    }
    dataGridView.Rows.Add();
}
```

Готово!

---

Можно динамически создавать датагриды (если нужно выводить несколько свойств) или листбоксы (если достаточно показать одно свойство, в нашем случае - имя).

Можно использовать `FlowLayoutPanel` - вложенные компоненты будет *плавать* по его поверхности, `TableLayoutPanel` - вложенные компоненты будут фиксированы в ячейках таблицы, или просто `Panel` - тогда местоположение необходимо задавать вручную.

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(user => user.Position);

flowLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    var panel = new TableLayoutPanel { Parent = flowLayoutPanel };
    var label = new Label { Parent = panel, Text = group.Key };
    var listBox = new ListBox { Parent = panel };

    foreach (var user in group)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(user.Name);
    }
}
```

При желании можно стилизовать контролы, добавив или удалив бордюры, цвет фона и прочее.